# how to Use express validator (7.0.2) for route.post()

Tags: node.js, express-validator

```
   // here i using route/users.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
var User = require('../models/user');
var multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

router.post('/register',upload.any(),
body('name','Name field is require!').notEmpty().escape()
,(req, res) =\> {
const result = validationResult(req);
if(result.isEmpty()){       
//return res.status(400).json({ errors: data.array() });
return res.send(`Hello, ${req.body.name}!`);
}else{
const { name, email, username, password, profileimage } = req.body;
var newUser = new User({
name: name,
email: email,
username: username,
password: password
});
newUser.save()
.then(()=\>{
console.log("Document saved successfully");
})
.catch((err)=\>{
console.log("Document saved Unsuccessfully");
})

        res.location('/');
        res.redirect('/');
    }
```

above code if i not use -" upload.any() " (my form where enctype="multipart/form-data") not post anything, and now if i use upload.any() nothing is happend.

I want validation result output - if have empty field show result error and if not empty field save it data into database.